# Why is my javascript Promise stuck as "pending"?

Tags: javascript, canvas, promise

I have a complex SVG that is drawn to a canvas, and this task needs to complete before other objects are drawn. Here's a fiddle simulating this:

https://jsfiddle.net/1hucuLg9/1/

```
//draw svg
var promise = new Promise(function(){
  drawSwatch(document.getElementById("mySwatch")); 
  //not typo, canvas context is referenced inside this function due to xml complexity in this fiddle 
});
//draw image
promise.then(function(){
  ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById("myImg",0,0,150,150));
});
```

You'll note in the fiddle that only the SVG is drawn, not the other image afterwards. The `Promise` used to draw the SVG is stuck as pending ... even though the inner javascript is all executed. What's going on?

Comment: You never `resolve` (or `reject`) your `promise`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add `myImg` only once the image inside `drawSwatch` has loaded - you can do this

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//hard code variables for example
var vw=300, vh=200, x=20, y=50, w=250, h=50; rx=10, ry=5, bg="#fae", theta=15, midptX=100, midptY=120, blur=5;

//helper function to draw swatch objects
function drawSwatch(currentSwatch, resolve){ // extra parameter
    var data = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="'+vw+'" height="'+vh+'">'+
    '<defs>'+
    '<filter id="f1">'+
    '<feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="'+blur+'" />'+
    '</filter>'+
    '</defs>'+
    '<rect class="shape" x="0" y="0" width="'+w+'" height="'+h+'" rx="'+rx+'" ry="'+ry+'" transform="translate('+x+','+y+') rotate('+theta+','+midptX+','+midptY+')" fill="'+bg+'" filter="url(#f1)"></rect>'+
    '</svg>';

    //now draw the svg to canvas
    var svg_data = encodeURIComponent(data);
    // create a dataURI version
    var url = 'data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, ' + svg_data;
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, vw, vh);
      resolve(); // call the passed in resolve function
    }
    img.src = url;
}

//draw svg
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve){ 
  drawSwatch(document.getElementById("mySwatch"), resolve); // call drawSwatch passing in the resolve function
});

promise.then(function(){
  ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById("myImg"),0,0,150,150);
});
```

added a second parameter to `drawSwatch`, which is the `resolve` function from the promise constructor function

Now the callback in promise.then wont be called until `img.onload` is fired

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v03wxh6z/1/) - in the fiddle, instead of calling resolve directly, I've put it in a setTimout, to show that `.then` isn't executed until the promise is actually resolved

Comment: AH yes, the SVG is draw behind the image (even without `setTimeout`) and the fiddle made it clear. The trick was putting the `resolve` inside the `onload`. Wonderful! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should **resolve** the promise. Promise [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) should be useful.

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  drawSwatch(document.getElementById("mySwatch"));
  resolve();
});
promise.then(function(){
  ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById("myImg",0,0,150,150));
});
```